# Search value with underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery

if I type in `A_ _ l _ e` in my search input field, then Apple would appear as result from my Array .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fruitsArray = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Pineapple"];
  $.each(fruitsArray, function(index, value) {
  $("#result").append(index + ": " + value + '<br>');
});
```

**search**

```
$("[name='username']").keyup(function() {
   words = $(this).val();
   //   alert(words.length);
   $('#result').text(username);
});
});
```

here i have display array in html using jquery

**html**

```
<body>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <div id="result"></div>  
</body>
```

Comment: you'll possibly need a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: You can replace `_` with `.` and make a regex out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example.

When `input keyup` event trigger, check the `fruitsArray` match and show matched items.

[Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) created with replacing `_` to `.` for **any single character**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fruitsArray = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Pineapple"];
    $.each(fruitsArray, function(index, value) {
        $("#result").append(index + ": " + value + '<br>');
    });

    $("[name='username']").keyup(function() {
        var words = $(this).val().replace(/_/g, '.');
        try{
          var reg = new RegExp('^'+words.toLowerCase()+'$');
          $("#result").html('');
          $.each(fruitsArray, function(index, value) {
              if(reg.test(value.toLowerCase()))
                $("#result").append(index + ": " + value + '<br>');
          });
        }
        catch(e){
          // regular expression error
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="username" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Update**

Add start with and end with

Comment: And I did `toLowerCase` to avoid case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace every instance of `_` with `.` (the single-character wildcard in regex) and test against the resulting regular expression:

```
new RegExp(pattern.replace(/_/g, ".")).test(string)
```

```js
$(function(){
  let fruitsArray = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Pineapple"];
  let re = new RegExp("A__le".replace(/_/g, "."));
  
  $.each(fruitsArray, function(index, value){
    if (re.test(value)) {
       $("#result").append(index + ": " + value + "<br>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```